# Next.js: How to import 3rd party module (css/images)?

Tags: webpack, next.js

Within `components/Header.jsx` I have this custom CSS import:

```
import '@dtbaker/my-shared-package/main.css'
```

which works fine within other projects (Gatsby/WordPress).

I'm attempting to get this working in Next.js and receiving this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'images/653c75ef9be6b32befc9913aabfd6414.png' in 'node_modules/@dtbaker/my-shared-package'
```

The file `node_modules/@dtbaker/my-shared-package/images/653c75ef9be6b32befc9913aabfd6414.png` does indeed exist locally.

### What I've tried:

1) Using a combination of these inside `next.config.js`

```
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
const withImages = require('next-images')
```

2) Adding custom webpack rules in `next.config.js` copied from the working WordPress setup, with a combination of `file-loader` and `url-loader` trying to match `.png` image files

3) Trying to add custom webpack rules in `next.config.js` for my own scss/css loader

### `main.css` contents:

The css I'm trying to import is simply referencing a relative image like this:

```
.Footer__logos___GRyec {
  background-image: url(images/653c75ef9be6b32befc9913aabfd6414.png);
```

### What next?

Which direction should I go to try to solve this? Custom webpack config? Scrapping 3rd party module all together?

Any ideas appreciated! Thanks

Comment: I may have to play with `resolve-url-loader` ?

Comment: did you try to move the image to `/static/images/` folder and change css to match that path?